# Query for products in a certain category

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple "**products**" table in DynamoDb. Each product has a `categories` attribute which is a set of category ids like this:

```
[{ "N" : "4" },{ "N" : "5" },{ "N" : "6" },{ "N" : "8" }]
```

The products table has `id` (hash key) and `accountId` (range key)

Is it possible to make a query to find all products that are in category 6 and accountId 1 **without making a scan**? Or can I model this some other way to do it?

If it were a relational database I would have a product-to-category table, and join the products. If I have a similar table in Dynamo, then I would need to make a GetItem for every product in the product table and that feels like a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like the best way to approach this would be to use a [GSI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html).

Your table is structured like this:

- hashKey: `id`
- rangeKey: `accountId`
- attribute - `categories`

You would create a global secondary index with this structure:

- hashKey: `accountId`
- rangeKey: `id`
- attribute- `categories`

You would then be able to query against this index using the criteria you mentioned:

1. `accountId = 1`
2. `categories contains 6`

Here is a quick example I coded up against DynamoDB local that projects all of the attributes on the index.

```java
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Index;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.QueryFilter;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.spec.QuerySpec;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeDefinition;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.CreateTableRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.GlobalSecondaryIndex;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeySchemaElement;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeyType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Projection;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProjectionType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughput;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScalarAttributeType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.Tables;
public class StackOverflow {

    private static final String EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "example_table";
    private static final String HASH_KEY = "id";
    private static final String RANGE_KEY = "accountId";
    private static final String GSI = "accountIdToId";
    private static final String CATEGORIES = "categories";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AmazonDynamoDB
            client =
            new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey"));
        client.setEndpoint("http://localhost:4000");
        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
        if (Tables.doesTableExist(client, EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME)) {
            client.deleteTable(EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
        }

        CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest();
        createTableRequest.withTableName(EXAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
        createTableRequest.withKeySchema(new KeySchemaElement(HASH_KEY, KeyType.HASH),
                                         new KeySchemaElement(RANGE_KEY, KeyType.RANGE));
        createTableRequest.withAttributeDefinitions(
            new AttributeDefinition(HASH_KEY, ScalarAttributeType.S),
            new AttributeDefinition(RANGE_KEY, ScalarAttributeType.S));
        createTableRequest.withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(15l, 15l));
        // GSI definition
        final GlobalSecondaryIndex
            accountIdToId =
            new GlobalSecondaryIndex().withIndexName(GSI).withKeySchema(
                new KeySchemaElement(RANGE_KEY, KeyType.HASH),
                new KeySchemaElement(HASH_KEY, KeyType.RANGE)).withProvisionedThroughput(
                new ProvisionedThroughput(10l, 10l)).withProjection(
                new Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.ALL));
        createTableRequest.withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(accountIdToId);

        final Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(createTableRequest);
        table.waitForActive();

        table.putItem(new Item()
                          .withPrimaryKey(HASH_KEY, "1", RANGE_KEY, "6")
                          .withNumberSet(CATEGORIES, 1, 2, 5, 6));

        table.putItem(new Item()
                                 .withPrimaryKey(HASH_KEY, "2", RANGE_KEY, "6")
                                 .withNumberSet(CATEGORIES, 5, 6));

        table.putItem(new Item()
                                 .withPrimaryKey(HASH_KEY, "5", RANGE_KEY, "6")
                                 .withNumberSet(CATEGORIES, 1, 2));

        table.putItem(new Item()
                                 .withPrimaryKey(HASH_KEY, "5", RANGE_KEY, "8")
                                 .withNumberSet(CATEGORIES, 1, 2, 6));

        System.out.println("Scan the table, no filters");
        table.scan().forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();

        final Index gsi = table.getIndex(GSI);

        System.out.println("Scan the GSI without filter");
        gsi.scan().forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Query the GSI with range key condition and contains");

        final QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec()
            .withHashKey(RANGE_KEY, "6")
            .withQueryFilters(new QueryFilter(CATEGORIES).contains(6));
        gsi.query(querySpec).forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Scan the table, no filters
{ Item: {accountId=6, id=1, categories=[1, 2, 5, 6]} }
{ Item: {accountId=6, id=5, categories=[1, 2]} }
{ Item: {accountId=8, id=5, categories=[1, 2, 6]} }
{ Item: {accountId=6, id=2, categories=[5, 6]} }

Scan the GSI without filter
{ Item: {accountId=6, id=1, categories=[1, 2, 5, 6]} }
{ Item: {accountId=6, id=5, categories=[1, 2]} }
{ Item: {accountId=8, id=5, categories=[1, 2, 6]} }
{ Item: {accountId=6, id=2, categories=[5, 6]} }

Query the GSI with range key condition and contains
{ Item: {accountId=6, id=1, categories=[1, 2, 5, 6]} }
{ Item: {accountId=6, id=2, categories=[5, 6]} }
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to Dynamo so please correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I've understood, `in` and `contains` are only supported by *scan* and not *query*?

Comment: @Christoffer I updated my answer to be more clear, as `contains` is what you want. You should be able to use both `in` and `contains` in either *scan* or *query**

Comment: Thanks for the example! I'm using the PHP SDK so I'm not totally understanding what you are doing. I have created a GSI; `accountID` as hash key and `id` as key. Then I'm trying to query like you do: `{"TableName":"products","KeyConditions":{"accountId":{"ComparisonOperator":"EQ","AttributeValueList":[{"N":"1"}]},"categories":{"ComparisonOperator":"CONTAINS","AttributeValueList":[{"N":"6"}]}},"IndexName":"accountId-id-index"}`. But I'm getting this error: `Query condition missed key schema element: id`

Comment: It is hard to tell in the comment if `categories` is a member of `KeyConditions`. It should be apart of the [`QueryFilter`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-QueryFilter) parameter. Also, make sure that your GSI has `accountId` as the hash key (which it does not look like from the error message).

Answer (score 0):

Make another table, and update it when you update your main table. Really, this is what happens in an RDBMS anyways, it's just that it's in the background. When Amazon set up secondary indexes for tables, they basically just automated what people had been doing all along.

Comment: If at all possible I would want to avoid this. If a product is placed in 5 categories I would have to maintain product data in 5 copies and it just feels risky :)

Comment: Unfortunately, when you have data in a structure in Dynamo, you can't index it. It's a simple beast. This is one thing I like about Mongo, you can index inside a structure.